# Finding peaks within a specified range in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to analyze an audio file so I generated the FFT of the signal and found the peaks above a certain threshold.
This is a part of the code:

```
%---------------------------Performing FFT--------------------------------%
 for i = 2:No_of_peaks

    song_seg = song(max_col(i-1):max_col(i)-1);
%     song_seg = song(max_col(6):max_col(7)-1);
    L = length(song_seg);    
    NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y

    seg_fft = fft(song_seg,NFFT);%/L;

    N=5;Fst1=50;Fp1=60; Fp2=1040; Fst2=1050;

%     d = fdesign.bandpass('N,Fst1,Fp1,Fp2,Fst2');
%     h = design(d);
%     seg_fft = filter(h, seg_fft);

%     seg_fft(1) = 0;
%     
    f = FS/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
    seg_fft2 = 2*abs(seg_fft(1:NFFT/2+1));
    L5 = length(song_seg);

    figure(1+i)
    plot(f,seg_fft2)
    title('Frequency spectrum of signal')
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    %xlim([0 2500])
    ylabel('|Y(f)|')
    ylim([0 300])

    [points, loc] = findpeaks(seg_fft2,'MINPEAKHEIGHT',20)
 end
```

Now that I have the `points` and `loc` i want to be able to extract the peaks that are between 60Hz and 1000Hz. How can i write a code to implement it and store the peak amplitudes as well as the corresponding frequency values???

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two similar ways of going about this. First, after you FFT, pick the subset of the spectrum containing the region of interest and apply the peak search routine *only* to that section:

```
 for i = 2:No_of_peaks

    % ... code steps where you fft etc here ...
    % ... now pick the region of interest

    fmin = 60;
    fmax = 1000;
    region_of_interest = fmax>f & f>fmin;
    froi = f(region_of_interest);  

    [points, loc] = findpeaks(seg_fft2(region_of_interest),'MINPEAKHEIGHT',20)

    % index into froi to find the frequency of the peaks
    fpeaks = froi(loc);

 end
```

A very similar alternative is to pick peaks, then pick the subset within the frequency region of interest, like so:

```
 for i = 2:No_of_peaks

    % lots of code here to fft etc ...

    [points, loc] = findpeaks(seg_fft2,'MINPEAKHEIGHT',20)

    % find the peaks within the region of interest 

    fmin = 60;
    fmax = 1000;
    peaks_of_interest = find(fmax>f(loc) & f(loc)>fmin);
    fpeaks = f(loc(peaks_of_interest));
    apeaks = points(loc(peaks_of_interest));  % magnitude of the peaks


 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

[PeakFinder](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25500-peakfinder)

Another easier method is to make the first derivative of your function (use a diff vector with your discrete frequencies) and then locate the peaks. The amplitudes can be taken from your original signal.